# RaspiCam on RPi 1 B+ doesn't show images

Tags: raspicam, raspbian-stretch, motion, picamera

I'm trying to get a livestream with the official raspicam (with IR; revision 1.3) working, which is attached on my Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+.

The problem is, that I get an gray screen when I'm accessing the camera-stream via webbrowser and it gives me the following error message: **`UNABLE TO OPEN VIDEO DEVICE ---- ERROR CAPTURING FIRST IMAGE`**

My webbrowser shows the following:
[image]

Here is what I already tried:

- I already installed motion and configured it like in some tutorials. The configuration file is here: http://txt.do/dzget
- When I run `raspistill -v` it does display a live image on my screen, so the camera itself works.
- I also did the command (and put it into autostart): `sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2`
- There is also an terminal named `/dev/video0`.
- I already uninstalled `fswebcam` and `ffmpeg` as suggested by some forum posts.
- The GPU has 256 MB memory.
- The folder which should contain the motion images is `/srv/motion`, but it is empty. The permissions are: 
  `pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /srv
  drwxr-xr-x 2 motion motion 4096 Jul  7 13:44 motion`

When I view the output of the motion service, there is nothing / it does nothing:

```
    pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo motion -n -c /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file /etc/motion/motion.conf
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Motion 4.0 Started
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to file (/var/log/motion/motion.log)
```

**Could it be possible, that Raspian Stretch isn't compatible with this old camera or Raspberry?Does anyone of you know a solution to my problem?**

Thank you for any help!

Comment: have you solved your issue? Two suggestions/questions: Have you checked the log file? sometimes whats logged in the log file is more detailed than what you get from the service output. Issues with camera are often in the beginning of a new logging session. Is there a reason you've set 'v4l2_palette 9'? IMHO, if raspistill produces an output, there is no reason why the camera should not work with motion.